# Convert "weird" strings to normal python strings

Tags: python, character-encoding

Context: I'm trying to convert characters like these:

To normal python strings (speedy, building, tuesday, etc) and save them into a new dataframe to be exported into a new excel file. For example, the charcter  (U+1D552) should be converted to a (U+00AA). I'm reading each string from an excel file using `read_excel`. Should I do some type of encoding = "utf-8"? on the read_excel function? Or is there a way using `re` to replace those characters? Or even encode("ascii").decode(utf-8)?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You want NFKC normalization: `unicodedata.normalize('NFKC', '   ')` returns `'BUILDING Speedy TUESDAY spaghetti'`

Comment: Do you really mean U+00AA or do you want U+0061?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `unicodedata` you can normalize unicode strings:

```py
>> from unicodedata import normalize
>> test_str = "   "
>> print(normalize('NFKC', test_str))
BUILDING Speedy TUESDAY spaghetti
```

Comment: Hi, thank you! It does :) The word "" still returns 2 weird characters ( and ), but Ill have a look a the package and figure something out with it :) Thanks